# Monitor is flashing black for a while after turning on

Tags: display, hardware-failure

So my LCD monitor is flashing black for a while soon after turning it on, whether it's connected to a PC or not. Already tried another PC and the power cable. Nothing changed.

Similar questions have already been asked, i already looked into them, they suggest that the cause is most likely bad capacitors or backlights. I only have a small addition which might help to confirm the cause or point me in another direction.

So.. at first, the flashing lasted for less than a minute, now a week later, the flashing usually lasts for much longer. Today it lasted nearly half an hour. When i switched to monitor's Eco settings, it stopped, when i changed it back to standard or any other, it started again and kept going. I switched back to Eco and after about an hour tried Standard again, it started again.

Eco settings means less power consumption and less brightness, which I imagine does confirm the bad capacitors or backlights theory? What do you think?

I was about to open the case and take a look at the capacitors anyway, but decided to ask a question just in case.

Comment: Yeah, can be bad capacitors. This is the point where I would simply replace the monitor.

Comment: Does it use an external power brick?

Comment: No, not external. Model's Benq GL2450 for what it matters. Also after inspecting it carefully, found out that it has 0 screws, there's no way to open it, at least i can't find it.